# How to show avatar and username (not only full name) on the login screen?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, login-screen, customization

I used ubuntu tweak to change the login background, but I need these other things as well:

- Show username (not only full name) and avatar if possible, in the login screen

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: There's hardly any information on how to theme Lightdm

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

> > 1. Get your image or avatar, make sure its a sensible size e.g. 96×96 pixels. If not, edit with your preferred image manipulator program, such as GIMP.
> > 2. Copy it to your home directory
> > 3. Rename it **.face**
> > 4. Logout and then see your new avatar on the login in screen.
> > 5. The same icon also shows up when you go into Users and Groups.

Comment: This is a good tip, thanks. But I already had the avatar configured through the GUI. The problem is that unity does not show it on the login screen. It only shows it in "User Accounts", and in the locked screen.