# Where are the login screen images stored on the HD

Tags: 12.04, desktop-background

I'm in ubuntu 12.04 using two monitors.

In the login screen in one monitor I have the purple background with the usernames list and the password text field. In the second monitor I have a version of the purple wallpaper with the ubuntu logo in white in the center, anyone knows where can I find this image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images are stored in `usr/share/ backgrounds`

If you want to change these images you just need to change your desktop wallpaper.  This will also set the back ground of the login screen (LightDM) to be the same.

[Instructions how to change the wallpaper in LightDM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm)

[Instructions how to configure LightDM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter)