# Is there a way to use LightDM and Unity but get a lock screen like GDM in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, lightdm, gdm, display-manager

I like the GDM locked screen theme a lot! But even if i set GDM as the Display Manager but log in to Unity session,the lock screen remains that oh LightDM...

I want to use LightDM as my login Display Manager(As it boots up faster than GDM) but GDM as my LockScreen DM(As it looks better than LightDM)...is this possible? and how?

Comment: There are options to configure/modify LightDM as shown in this QA, but your question is very specific, therefore very localized.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter

Comment: I use Lightdm to handle account login but gnome-screensaver to lock my system. Xscreensaver should be uninstalled.