# After installing KDE desktop only KDE login

Tags: 12.04, login, kde, dpkg

I installed KDE via the `sudo apt-get install kde-plasm-desktop` command (I wanted less packages than installing the Kubuntu-desktop would give me) and now I get the KDE (or is it Kubuntu?) login screen:

[image: KDE Login Screen]

This is what I get, and I can't select the different DEs I have installed. I would like to go back to the default Ubuntu login screen if that is possible. Is there some sort of dpkg command I should run, because that would kinda make sense.

Thanks in advance (that is, if you solve my problem. If you don't well, then I suppose I could thank you for trying to help...I dunno :D)

Comment: If that is `kdm` then just try `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and choose lightdm. If it is the `lightdm-kde-greeter` try this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter

Comment: Thanks @tvn! I knew I had to do something with a DM and dpkg. I was looking around for what to do when you answered it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If that is kdm then just try `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and choose lightdm. If it is the lightdm-kde-greeter try this question [How to change the LightDM theme/greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter).

This was @tvn's answer via a comment, so if @tvn wants to answer it himself I will accept his, otherwise I will accept mine to close the question.

Answer (score 6):

To select different DE, all you have to do is click on the little blue down arrow, and choose the DE that you want.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: Ah, well, I will remember that! I didn't know that and didn't try it out. Thanks! Now that I think about it I kinda like the KDE login screen, it's nice

Comment: FYI - In 12.10 and up KDM has been replaced by LightDM for Kubuntu installations as the default. Of course you can manually install it again, though.