# 14.04 LTS login window is hidden until mouse pointer is moved to the right

Tags: boot, 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade, login

I've upgraded from dual-booting Ubuntu 12.04 LTS / Windows 7 to dual-booting Ubuntu 14.04 LTS / Windows 7.

Before the upgrade, when booting Ubuntu, the login window would appear as expected, waiting for my password. But after upgrading, the login window appears for less than 1 sec (on a solid purple background with a grid of dots) before getting "covered over" by a multicolored wallpaper that says "14.04 LTS" in the lower left corner.

From this point I can get to the desktop either by entering my password "blindly" (with invisible login window), or I can make the login window visible again by moving the mouse a few inches to the right. (The mouse pointer behaves as though it's initially off the left edge of the screen.)

**Q: What can I do to prevent the login window from getting hidden in the first place?**

UPDATE: In case this might be relevant ...

`dir /etc/lightdm` -->

```
lightdm.conf
lightdm.conf~
lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu.conf
users.conf
```

and

`cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` -->

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session = unity-greeter
user-session = ubuntu
allow-guest = false
```

Per the [answer by Xieerqi](https://askubuntu.com/a/515644/315827), replacing `greeter-session = unity-greeter` with `greeter-session = lightdm-gtk-greeter` is a viable workaround, but does not solve the issue with `unity-greeter`. Since [one of the links in that answer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#Unity_greeter) refers to `lightdm-unity-greeter` (i.e., with the prefix `lightdm-`), I also tried the line `greeter-session = lightdm-unity-greeter`, without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login screen is called greeter in Ubuntu. While I can't think of exact fix, I can suggest a work-around. Basic idea is changing the greeter. Now, depending on which desktop manager program you are using , the configuration settings will be different. I assume you have lightdm manager, which is default that comes with Ubuntu. Here's procedure for replacing lightdm's default unity greeter with lightdm-gtk-greeter.

1. When Ubuntu starts and gets to login screen, **press Ctrl+Alt+F2**  to get to tty terminal screen. Login with your user name and password.
2. Enter the following command `sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter` , it will prompt you for password, and after you enter, it will run a bunch of commands, asking also if the size of installation is okay. This will install the lightdm-gtk-greeter on your machine.
3. After installation is done, we need to alter lightdm's settings so that the default greeter is replaced with lightdm-gtk-greeter. Still in the terminal window enter `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` . This will open configuration file  lightdm.conf in the Nano command line text editor(very useful app, by the way).
4. Add the following line to this file `greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter` ; Press **Ctrl+O**, it will prompt you for file name to write, don't change file name - just press enter. Once it says wrote, press **Ctrl+X** to exit.
5. Now the settings have been changed. Reboot the computer using this command `sudo shutdown -r now` and the window for username and password should be placed in the center of the screen now, which is how gtk greeter normally looks.

This procedure works for a variety of other greeters. However if you have different desktop environment, like gdm, the procedure will be slightly different, but the main premise is the same - entering command line,downloading proper greeter, altering configuration files, reboot. I've listed additional information and links bellow. Let me know if that helps. Cheers !

Sources:  [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM) , [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter), [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM), and some personal experience messing with lightdm settings;

**Bonus** : here's some of my favorite command line apps in case GUI stuff doesn't work or you can't log into graphical shell

1. Midnight Commander - file manager; `sudo apt-get install mc`
2. elinks command-line web browser; `sudo apt-get install elinks`
3. moc command line music player; `sudo apt-get install moc` and mocp to actually run it;

Comment: Thanks for the all the useful details. After steps 1-5,  I'm now happily using `lightdm-gtk-greeter`. (Still, it would be satisfying to know how to fix whatever was going on with `unity-greeter`.) I'll definitely take a look at the apps you mention.

Comment: BTW ... When I first edited `lightdm.conf`, I inadvertently put a single space at the end of the line `greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter`. Amazingly, *this resulted in no greeter at all*, so I repeatedly logged in using Ctrl-Alt-F2 (which I hadn't known about til now) until eventually finding that the problem was just that single space.

Comment: That's one of the annoying parts about configuration files and scripting - unix/linux command line hates spaces.  As for unity greeter , there's some other config files which you could investigate.  Look through some of the links I added in source part. I will post a bit later copies of how my config file for unity look like.  Right now I'm on mobile so haven't access to those

Comment: Hello again, friend ! I apologize for late reply. So I've thought a bit about unity greeter, and I think the best bet to fix unity greeter is to reinstall it. This can be accomplished with the command : sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-greeter. See if that helps. And you do already know how to change greeters, too, so should be piece of cake, right?

Comment: I reinstalled unity greeter per your advice, but it seems to have had no effect. The login window still gets hidden by the multicolored wallpaper -- which looks the same as the default desktop wallpaper, except it has "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" in the lower left corner, and has a large version of the circular Ubuntu logo in the center of the screen. (I turned off the grid of dots using Ubuntu Tweak.)