# Which edit functions are acceptable in grub?

Tags: command-line, grub2, lightdm

I made a major mistake by putting in this code:

```
vim /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and then changing the line

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

to

```
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

But now I get a low graphics error. I found some answers on how to fix this, but I am struggling with opening the terminal to do it. The instructions on this website [How to change the LightDM theme/greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter) would be helpful if I could get into the terminal, but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> nothing happens except the cursor freezes.

So I am looking for a workaround and I considered changing grub as the terminal does open up there. But I ran into a new problem - grub does not recognize `sudo` and other commands.

Comment: What happens on Ctrl+Alt+F1? You should get to console.

Comment: I don't, my mouse freezes and I don't get to the console. I stay on the same low graphics screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get to grub menu, you can choose to boot in recovery mode. Do it.

Then choose the option "root"

There you can run

```
mount -o remount,rw /
nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and edit this file. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

Then run

```
reboot
```

Comment: @Pilot6-It doesn't work yet but I was able to follow your commands. What I am thinking is the greeter-session is worded wrong somehow. I was able to find the configuration file. It is /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf