# Ubuntu Lockscren Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, gnome, xubuntu, xfce, lock-screen

I installed the ubuntu-desktop, but I still get the Xfce lockscreen. Is there anyway to get the Ubuntu lockscreen instead?

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for:

[How to change the LightDM theme/greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter)

You'd want the "unity-greeter"