# What is the default lock screen for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, lock-screen

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Unity 7.4.0 and have been messing around with the screensavers and lock screens.  After trying out `xscreensaver` and a few others, I tried to go back to the default because I decided that that one looked better than all the others, but I couldn't find it.  Most people say that `gnome-screensaver` is the default for Xenial.  I don't think that's right because when my screen is locked with `gnome-screensaver`, it looks nothing like it did before.  It shows an ugly white box with buttons that say Switch User and Unlock and asks for my password.  How do I revert back to the default lock screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default display manager is `lightdm`, which uses `unity-greeter` as the default lockscreen.

Comment: Umm I think the steps to set it up would improve your answer?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix technically...the exact question was answered :/. Perhaps try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: @nullmeta I ran that command and uninstalled gnome-screensaver.  It didn't work.  Is there anything else I should try?

Comment: @CurticeGough I'm not near a computer but I found an old post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter#75819) that may be a solution, like I said I'm not near a computer to verify.

Comment: @Android Dev Ok I edited /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf to use unity-greeter and then rebooted, but then it just wouldn't lock at all.

Comment: @CurticeGough And this Ubuntu wiki may be helpful as it explains the config location [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)

Comment: What do you mean it wouldn't lock at all?

Comment: @nullmeta When I pressed `CTRL+ALT+L` the screen would not lock.

Comment: @CurticeGough - Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/75819/518562

Comment: @AndroidDev I don't see how changing the greeter will fix the lock screen.

Comment: @CurticeGough the greeter *is* the lockscreen.

Comment: @AndroidDev oh sorry.  Ok I changed it to `unity-greeter` and uninstalled `gnome-screensaver` but it still didn't work.

Comment: @CurticeGough - Have you tried to good old reboot?

Comment: @AndroidDev yes.  It has been doing this for about a month.

Comment: @CurticeGough Have you done `sudo apt-get purge lightdm-gtk-greeter`?

Comment: @AndroidDev yes