# No config file found for LightDM

Tags: login, xorg, lightdm, login-screen

I am trying to change the greeter-session in LightDm, but I am unable to find any lightdm.conf in *etc/ lightdm*. 
This is what's inside etc/lightdm -

[image: etc/lightdm/]

The lightdm.conf.d folder is empty.

Also file search does return a *lightdm.conf* in *etc/ init*, but it doesn't seem to be the file I need.

So, how shuold I change the greeter-session,  should I create a lightdm.conf file ?

P.S. Distro - Ubuntu 18.04 with latest Gnome version.

**EDIT :** [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/816084/880212). This seems to work.

Comment: I entered `locate lightdm.conf` in my system and it found /etc/init/lightdm.conf along with a number of other possibly related files.  However a search for `lightdm` using my menu opened a Login Window configuration applet titled `LightDM GTK+ Greeter` that allows me to use a GUI tool to change things - why not use that?

Comment: @starkus purging and reinstalling didn't bring back the missing .conf file. Although I managed to edit the greeter-session via a workaround in this answer 
[askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/816084/880212)