# The lightdm login screen is wrong

Tags: login, lightdm, 20.10, cinnamon

These are the steps I took to install lightdm:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install lightdm  # I have set lightdm instead of gdm3 in the interactive menu
sudo apt install slick-greeter
sudo apt install lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings
sudo apt install light-themes
sudo apt install cinnamon-desktop-environment
```

After I restarted the computer, I got the following login screen:

[image]

Instead of this example image:

[image]

Why?

Comment: You did not do a sudo apt upgrade to make sure all apps are up to date? A normal step after what you did do.

Comment: Does this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter answer your question? The first image you have posted shows the `lightdm-gtk-greeter`. The second is the `unity-greeter`.

Comment: yes, I have done dist-upgrade

Comment: @Stormlord Add this as accepted answer!

Comment: @MarioPalumbo It's OK. I just reposted someone else's answer.  ;-)